# Rotation of 3d plane

Tags: image-rotation, planerotation

I have a set of points on a 3d plane A, the centroid of those points, and the normal vector A1 of the plane A and I also know the normal vector B1 of plane B.

How do I rotate the points on plane A to plane B which pivot at the centroid?

I have a transformation matrix as follows:

```
rmat = matrix([ x*x*C+c    x*y*C-z*s  x*z*C+y*s ],
              [ y*x*C+z*s  y*y*C+c    y*z*C-x*s ]
              [ z*x*C-y*s  z*y*C+x*s  z*z*C+c   ])

newPoint = rmat * oldPoint

costheta = dot(A1, B1)/|A1 * B1|
c = costheta
s = sqrt(1-c*c)
C = 1-c
```

My results are rotated and translated.

[image]